# Unable to connect with LTE modem after upgrading to 18.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, 18.04, modem

I've recently upgraded (via fresh reinstall) from 17.10 to 18.04 and am trying to connect my LTE modem to my telco.

Laptop: Lenovo T470s
Modem: Sierra MBIM [1199:907B] (cdc-wdm0)
Location: Australia
Telco: Optus
APN: internet

When I try to connect, I get this in my syslog.

```
May 23 08:31:12 T470s NetworkManager[857]: <info>  [1527028272.0523] device (cdc-wdm0): Activation: starting connection 'Optus Mobile Internet' (0bf40498-37c8-41f3-8518-8318ed072033)
May 23 08:31:12 T470s NetworkManager[857]: <info>  [1527028272.0524] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="0bf40498-37c8-41f3-8518-8318ed072033" name="Optus Mobile Internet" pid=6852 uid=1000 result="success"
May 23 08:31:12 T470s NetworkManager[857]: <info>  [1527028272.0525] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 23 08:31:12 T470s ModemManager[864]: <info>  Simple connect started...
May 23 08:31:12 T470s ModemManager[864]: <info>  Simple connect state (4/8): Wait to get fully enabled
May 23 08:31:12 T470s ModemManager[864]: <info>  Simple connect state (5/8): Register
May 23 08:31:12 T470s ModemManager[864]: <info>  Simple connect state (6/8): Bearer
May 23 08:31:12 T470s ModemManager[864]: <info>  Simple connect state (7/8): Connect
May 23 08:31:12 T470s ModemManager[864]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1: state changed (registered -> connecting)
May 23 08:31:12 T470s NetworkManager[857]: <info>  [1527028272.0588] modem["cdc-wdm0"]: modem state changed, 'registered' --> 'connecting' (reason: user-requested)
May 23 08:31:13 T470s ModemManager[864]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1: 3GPP Registration state changed (home -> unknown)
May 23 08:31:13 T470s ModemManager[864]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1: 3GPP Registration state changed (unknown -> searching)
May 23 08:31:13 T470s kernel: [36009.611492] kauditd_printk_skb: 220 callbacks suppressed
May 23 08:31:13 T470s kernel: [36009.611496] audit: type=1400 audit(1527028273.692:102945): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/proc/759/wchan" pid=759 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
May 23 08:31:13 T470s kernel: [36009.611955] audit: type=1400 audit(1527028273.692:102946): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/proc/2128/wchan" pid=759 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
May 23 08:31:13 T470s kernel: [36009.612360] audit: type=1400 audit(1527028273.692:102947): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/proc/2129/wchan" pid=759 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
May 23 08:31:13 T470s kernel: [36009.612607] audit: type=1400 audit(1527028273.692:102948): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/proc/2129/cgroup" pid=759 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
May 23 08:31:13 T470s kernel: [36009.612833] audit: type=1400 audit(1527028273.692:102949): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/proc/2142/wchan" pid=759 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
May 23 08:31:13 T470s kernel: [36009.613500] audit: type=1400 audit(1527028273.696:102950): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/proc/2142/cgroup" pid=759 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
May 23 08:31:13 T470s kernel: [36009.613719] audit: type=1400 audit(1527028273.696:102951): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/proc/2163/wchan" pid=759 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
May 23 08:31:13 T470s kernel: [36009.614152] audit: type=1400 audit(1527028273.696:102952): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/proc/2165/wchan" pid=759 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
May 23 08:31:13 T470s kernel: [36009.614560] audit: type=1400 audit(1527028273.696:102953): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/proc/2202/wchan" pid=759 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
May 23 08:31:13 T470s kernel: [36009.614957] audit: type=1400 audit(1527028273.696:102954): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/proc/2205/wchan" pid=759 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
May 23 08:31:16 T470s ModemManager[864]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1: state changed (connecting -> searching)
May 23 08:31:16 T470s NetworkManager[857]: <info>  [1527028276.3226] modem["cdc-wdm0"]: modem state changed, 'connecting' --> 'searching' (reason: user-requested)
May 23 08:31:16 T470s NetworkManager[857]: <warn>  [1527028276.3228] modem-broadband[cdc-wdm0]: failed to connect modem: Failure
May 23 08:31:16 T470s NetworkManager[857]: <info>  [1527028276.3229] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: prepare -> failed (reason 'unknown', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 23 08:31:16 T470s NetworkManager[857]: <warn>  [1527028276.3246] device (cdc-wdm0): Activation: failed for connection 'Optus Mobile Internet'
May 23 08:31:16 T470s NetworkManager[857]: <info>  [1527028276.3272] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 23 08:31:18 T470s ModemManager[864]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1: 3GPP Registration state changed (searching -> registering)
May 23 08:31:18 T470s ModemManager[864]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1: 3GPP Registration state changed (registering -> home)
May 23 08:31:18 T470s ModemManager[864]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1: state changed (searching -> registered)
May 23 08:31:18 T470s NetworkManager[857]: <info>  [1527028278.1845] modem["cdc-wdm0"]: modem state changed, 'searching' --> 'registered' (reason: unknown)
```

Is Apparmor blocking the connection or something else?

Any help in directing my in my troubleshooting would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have the same issue.